# How to set up Pi3 as access point without creating new subnet and without using bridge

Tags: pi-3, networking

I have a Pi3 with eth0 and wlan0 interfaces. It's plugged into router via Ethernet. would like to set it up as a wireless AP. The solutions available usually set up a new subnet. I don't want that. It has to be on the same network. Some suggest setting up a bridge between wlan0 and eth0, however this ruins my eth0 interface and causes all kinds of problem, e.g. can no longer SSH into the Pi. 
Hence, I need to be able to keep both interfaces and just pass through all the traffic from wlan0 to eth0. I looked at iptables and routing tables but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should still be able to ssh into the RPi in a bridged configuration provided you assign an IP address to the bridge (br0) interface.

Comment: yeah, I figured this out. What I have done now is I have assigned the IP that I used to assign to eth0 to br0. However, I am still not convinced everything is working properly. So, when I bridge, does this effectively remove the two interfaces and replace it with one?  Then how do I now distinguish which traffic came from where? I need to be able to say if traffic comes over wlan0 do something with it.

Comment: If you want to do something with the traffic between interfaces, you most likely want a router configuration. A bridge simply passes traffic (generally) between both interfaces. As you suspected, both physical interfaces are bound to one logical interface. As far as IP is concerned, they're the same.

Comment: But a router is only useful if there are different subnets, right? I want everything to be on the same subnet. Ok, let's take a step back. My initial issue is the following. If I (1) set up Pi as an Access Point on wlan0 using hostapd and (2) have the Pi connectect via eth0 to my router, why can I not authenticate on the AP (network is there but cannot log in with correct password)? I have assigned static IP addresses to both wlan0 and eth0 and ifconfig shows that they are both up and working.